# curl_exec() always returns false

Tags: php, curl

I have written this simple piece of code :

```
$ch = curl_init();

//Set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$website_content = curl_exec ($ch);
```

In my case `$website_content` comes as `false`.
Can anyone suggest/advice something what could be going wrong?

Comment: Consult [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) for error details and post these here, please.

Comment: @LinusKleen If you post the curl_error() as an answer I'll upvote it as it allowed me to see what my problem was.

Comment: What exactly was the problem? What error did `curl_error()` reveal?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Error checking and handling is the programmer's friend. Check the return values of the initializing and executing cURL functions. [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and [`curl_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) will contain further information in case of failure:

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Check if initialization had gone wrong*    
    if ($ch === false) {
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
    }

    // Better to explicitly set URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/');
    // That needs to be set; content will spill to STDOUT otherwise
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // Set more options
    curl_setopt(/* ... */);
    
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check the return value of curl_exec(), too
    if ($content === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }

    // Check HTTP return code, too; might be something else than 200
    $httpReturnCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    /* Process $content here */

} catch(Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);

} finally {
    // Close curl handle unless it failed to initialize
    if (is_resource($ch)) {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> The `curl_init()` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) states:

> Returns a cURL handle on success, **FALSE** on errors.

I've observed the function to return `FALSE` when you're using its `$url` parameter and the domain could not be resolved. If the parameter is unused, the function *might* never return `FALSE`. Always check it anyways, though, since the manual doesn't clearly state what "errors" actually are.

Comment: +1: Simple and straight trouble-shooting for curl in PHP on `curl_exec` FALSE return. - [Curl Verbose Mode in PHP example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9571305/367456)

Comment: and do not forget curl_close($ch);

Comment: It's implicitly closed when the variable goes out of scope, but sure. I made it a complete example. Thanks, @RafikBari.

Comment: And make sure to call `curl_close` after `curl_error` and `curl_errno`, otherwise you'll get a `false` here, too. Happened to me. True story.

Comment: In my case I had called curl_close() before calling curl_exec(). This answer set me straight after pulling my code apart several times.

Comment: @Valkay Close before exec? Are you running that code in a loop?

Comment: +1 In my case the error was related to HTTP 2.0 - `HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)`. cURL stopped working suddenly, and I had no idea why - nothing was changed on my end, nor on the remote end. Using `curl_error($ch)` helped debug it.

Comment: Mine was a strange one; the try block didn't break, the HTTP response was 200, and although the content was false, no error was displaying via `curl_error`. However, `curl_errno` displayed "77", and a quick look up found that PHP cURL was using an outdated set of root certificates to verify server certificates. Some tutorials advised to reinstall a new one, but simply restarting PHP-FPM fixed the issue.

Answer (score 45):

In my case I need to set `VERIFYHOST` and `VERIFYPEER` to `false`, like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

before the call to `curl_exec($ch)`.

Because i am working between two development environments with self-assigned certificates.
With valid certificates there is no need to set `VERIFYHOST` and `VERIFYPEER` to `false` because the `curl_exec($ch)` method will work and return the response you expect.

Comment: You are a savior

Comment: You saved me 15hours of tears

Comment: Man... U R my hero! No words to thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me yesterday and in my case was because I was following a PDF manual to develop some module to communicate with an API and while copying the link directly from the manual, for some odd reason, the `hyphen` from the copied link was in a different encoding and hence the `curl_exec()` was always returning `false` because it was unable to communicate with the server.

It took me a couple hours to finally understand the diference in the characters bellow:

```
https://www.e‐example.com/api
https://www.e-example.com/api
```

Every time I tried to access the link directly from a browser it converted to something like`https://www.xn--eexample-0m3d.com/api`.

It may seem to you that they are equal but if you check the encoding of the `hyphens` [here](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html) you'll see that the first `hyphen` is a unicode characters [U+2010](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2010/index.htm) and the other is a [U+002D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm).

Hope this helps someone.