# Freebase API call works in browser but fails with curl

Tags: php, json, curl, freebase

I'm trying to receive data from the Freebase API. I manually built a working API call which gave me a valid JSON response in my browser. So I wrote a PHP Function which should do exactly that:

```
$service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search';
$params = array(
           'filter' => '(all name:"Avatar")',
           'lang' => 'en',
           'type' => 'film/film',
           'key' => Configure::read('Api.Key')
         );
$url = $service_url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
```

The response I get is `NULL`, but if I take the built URL and enter it into my Chrome REST Plugin or view it directly in the browser, I get a valid response. If the url is valid, why would my curl function fail?

Comment: Does this work if you just include the key inline like: 'key' => 'XXX-XXX-XXX'? I just tried that and it works for me.

Comment: Have you checked what the output of curl_error($ch) is after the curl_exec call?

Answer (score 1):

For me by adding the below line worked.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are seeing `NULL` because the `curl_exec` returns `false` and then the `json_decode` converts the `false` to `NULL`.

This means, as you suspected, that `curl_exec` is failing.  I'm not sure why, but I would start by debugging with [curl_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and [curl_errno()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) to get more information on what is causing curl to fail.

Reference: [curl_exec() always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227909/curl-exec-always-returns-false)