# Slack Incoming Webhook with PHP form

Tags: php, html, json, slack-api

I'm trying to create a PHP script that automatically pushes text from `<textarea>` in my webform to Slack channel.

HTML:

```
<form action="http://main.xfiddle.com/<?php echo pf_file('g7f-ds0'); ?>" method="post" id="myform" name="myform">   
<textarea name="text" id="" rows="3" cols="30">
</textarea> <br /><br />
<button id="mysubmit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button><br /><br /></form>
```

I managed to write a PHP script that posts hard coded message to Slack like this:

```
    <?php

//API Url
$url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T02NZ01FU/B08TTAPGE/000000000000000000';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$payload = array(
   ’text' => 'Testing text with PHP'
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($payload);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

But for some reason when I try to get text from `<textarea name="text" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>` and save it into a variable then it doesn't work. I add this to the beginning of PHP to set the text variable:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
$textdata = $_POST['text'];
```

and then change the $payload to

```
'text' => $textdata
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple example of how to use slack incoming webhook with `curl`

```
<?php
define('SLACK_WEBHOOK', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/yyy/zzz');
function slack($txt) {
  $msg = array('text' => $txt);
  $c = curl_init(SLACK_WEBHOOK);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('payload' => json_encode($msg)));
  curl_exec($c);
  curl_close($c);
}
?>
```

Snippet taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/urigoren/be3190dd8a1d1d84994e1c066f2845b0)

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely issues here.

1. The PHP formatting in your post is incorrect.

   Replace `’text' => 'Testing text with PHP'` with
   `'text' => 'Testing text with PHP'`
2. Your curl is not set up correctly.  Please see the following posts to [debug curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227909/curl-exec-always-returns-false) and to fix what is likely wrong - [no trusted SSL certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok)