# Unable to make external calls from PHP script using cURL

Tags: php, apache

I am using ubuntu server, testing to fetch an external url with wget and cURL in terminal via putty.

```
wget www.google.com
```

works fine and i got response.

```
curl -v www.google.com
```

works find and i got response

Now in my php script i have

```
$url = 'www.google.com';
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$jsonData = curl_exec($curlSession);
curl_close($curlSession);

var_dump("curl without proxy ", $jsonData);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
```

I am getting NULL as response

[image]

When i test it with a fresh server or localhost or another server, the code is working fine.

Is there any settings that need to be checked. In php.ini settings

```
allow_url_fopen is ON
```

Comment: I suggest you make sure errors are properly displayed (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and run it again to get an explicit error message, then you can start debugging.

Comment: Thanks. But no errors were thrown. Note, this is a working code on my local and other server

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Like: anything? Remove all unneccessary parts from your code to see what happens

Comment: Are you literally calling `www.google.com`? And if so, why would you expect JSON to be returned?

Comment: www.google.com was an example. I am not sure we can publicly say the apis developers call.

Comment: @NicoHaase My question was exactly how to debug the problem, where no errors are thrown. I also confirm this is a working code and php file has no other codes

Comment: What else did you try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227909/curl-exec-always-returns-false holds some hints about what to do if `curl_exec` returns false

Comment: Thanks to all. That server was behind proxy. Once we define the port for proxy everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and actually by removing the json_decode the result is showing. This is because you try to convert from json a html response. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) does not return json but html.

You can see json_decode errors by adding the option JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR at the fourth parameter like this :

```
$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession),false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

The final code looks like this without the json_decode :

```
$url = 'www.google.com';
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
//This is where the problem was, the response wasn't json but html
$jsonData = curl_exec($curlSession);

curl_close($curlSession);

var_dump("curl without proxy ", $jsonData);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
```

What i don't undestand however is how your code can work in another server. Are you calling another url ? Because [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) might just be an example for you to hide the real url of the server for company reasons

Comment: Awesome. But did not work. As i mentioned, i was trying to debug on multiple servers. By mistake copy pasted the code from where i was expecting json data. I mentioned google.com since it is easy understanding